# Second Monitor not Displaying on Boot up

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have 2 monitors connected one with VGA and one with HDMI. When I boot up the HDMI one doesn't doesn't display anything. I can tell it is recognizing some kind of input (it doesn't go into sleep mode). If I turn the monitor off and on it will sometimes flicker and other times just flicker. Sometimes unplugging it from my computer and plugging it back in will work. Other times resetting my display settings will work. I thought this was a drivers issue with my nVidia card so I switched over to my Intel internal graphics but this didn't help.

I using 13.10 with Intel Ivybridge graphics (previously and nVidia GT620 card). Any help is appreciated!!

[image: Machine Specs]
Video Driver (from running lshw -c video): driver=i915 ( should just be the Intel one like I said in the question
Kernel: 3.8.0-35-generic
X: 1.14.5
 Also wanted to say that this only occurs on boot or when left idle for some time. Its Lenovo IdeaCentre K410 Desktop.

Comment: To the point of the answer about graphics above, I had to set my Lenovo w520 graphics to Discrete (meaning to only use the Nvidia card, not the Intel graphics card) in the BIOS. Problem solved for me.

Comment: Well, I already have it set to integrated graphics by default so I'm not sure changing it to discrete would help. Do you think it would make a difference?

Comment: So the screen works fine as soon as it has booted? The problem only appears while booting? If so, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related but I had a similar problem with lenovo w500 laptop and red hat.  My problem was that graphics adaptor has a bios option to conserve battery but only works in windows.  Had to enable offboard graphics adaptor full to get it to work.  very difficult to tell if this applies to you.   Might try posting more info from system log and PC specs.

Comment: I am also using a Lenovo so it may have the same BIOS setting. I'll try that and then see if it works and post more details.

Comment: I don't seem to see an option. I originally had the problem on my external graphics card so I don't think that solution would work.